# Publish a library for Python made with Rust to pypi

Tags: python, pypi, pyo3

Is this possible?
After some research, it seems that the library setuptools-rust can be used for easy distribution, but it looks like the user also needs this library setuptools-rust.
Is there any way to make the installation work without setuptools-rust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should try having a look at Maturin: https://github.com/PyO3/maturin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).